# Thermostat above or under light switch?

Tags: switch, thermostat, placement

Currently, my thermostat is in the dining room, right at the entrance to the hallway. But exactly there I would like to install a light switch for the hallway. The thermostat is the same height as the other light switches. The backside of that wall is accessible so I can (somewhat) easily access wiring from both the switch and thermostat.

If I install the light switch at the same place where currently the thermostat is, where shall I best put the thermostat? Under the light switch feels a bit too low. One option is next to the light switch (on the left side; on the right side is the door) and another is on top.

Is there any best practice?

(I know there are guidelines for doorbells, toilet paper holders etc)

Comment: Which direction does the thermostat wiring come in from? Shorter or slacker is easy, longer or stretching the wire is more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

If above, not too close because some dimmer and smart switches produce heat.

Best is at eye level so you can read the display easily.

Comment: But do eye level *average* for the people in the house (e.g. tall husband, short wife)!

Comment: @Huesmann if you know a way to keep wives away from thermostats .... :):):)

Comment: Locking thermostat cover! :D

Comment: My wife can pick locks just fine…

Answer (score 1):

You can place the thermostat where you like. However, the air stratifies, or goes into layers so the area near the ceiling is hotter than the floor.  So, avoid the extremes.  Keep it away from heat sources, light switches will not produce much heat.

Once you are using it you soon find that it appears to be inaccurate, this is because the air doesn't mix well in the room, without a fan.  And you ignore the absolute value of the temperature and start remembering the values that are comfortable with.  That's my experience.